# PriorityBlockingQueue: is it realy blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency, blocking

I read about `PriorityBlockingQueue`, and seems I've got some delusions about it. You can see four statements below. I hope if you disagree with them you'll correct me.

1. Blocking collections block a thread if the thread can't execute operation on collection. (Block till condition when the thread can continue). Main purpose - producer-consumer scheme.
2. Non-blocking collections doesn't block a thread and the thread proceeds execution. Main purpose - schemes where reader shouldn't wait for writer. I mean schemes where the delay read-oparation delay after write is not significant.
3. As it follows from the name of `PriorityBlockingQueue` - it's a blocking collection.
4. `PriorityBlockingQueue` offer such non-blocking methods as `poll`, `remove`, `put` etc; and seems only `poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` and `take` methods are blocking.

**Conclusion:** From the fourth statement I conclude that `PriorityBlockingQueue` **can be used both as blocking and non-blocking queue**.

**Question:** Am I right in my conclusion? Can I say the same about all other blocking collections?

Comment: Wouldn't writing some code to test this be better than posting a Q on SO and waiting for someone to give you the answer? Is there a particular part of the documentation that isn't clear on what those methods do?

Comment: @BrianRoach I write this question after testing all those methods by my own. I just want to check if I understand all correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. Sometimes it can be useful to not block for some operations, even if you're using it regularly with blocking purposes.

From the javadoc for the `BlockingQueue` interface:

> A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue
>   to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to
>   become available in the queue when storing an element.

So the blocking property is an addition to normal queue functionality. Soo a blocking queue is a queue, but a queue is not necessarily a blocking one.

Comment: can I say the same about all other standard implementations of blocking collections/maps.